# How to create jobs in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, jobs

How to create scheduled jobs in PostgreSQL?

Comment: I'm not sure why people downvoted your question. It's not silly, and some DBMSs have the concept of job. It's a way to schedule tasks without having access to the system - something that an analyst, for example, shouldn't have.

Answer (score 9):

PostgreSQL doesn't have the concept of scheduled jobs.

You can use

- [cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) or the like on Unix.
- [Windows task scheduler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Scheduler) on Microsoft operating systems.

With these, just use `psql` to connect the db and feed it a sql file.

```
psql -d myDb -f "mySQL.sql"
```

If you want an EXTENSION that does some of this, you can check out [pg_cron](https://github.com/citusdata/pg_cron).

Answer (score 7):

You can configure your recurring tasks by creating database jobs in PostgreSQL. PostgreSQL provides one external tool to configure PostgreSQL jobs, its name is `PGAgent`.

[`PGAgent`](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/development/pgagent.html) (a part of pgAdminIII) is an external tool by the Postgres community which is used to create and manage database jobs.

For your further reference: [How to create job in PostgreSQL](http://www.dbrnd.com/2015/05/how-to-create-job-in-postgresql/)